# Remove character after specific column

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file:

```
Offset(V)  Name                    PID   PPID   Thds     Hnds   Sess  Wow64 Start                          Exit                          
---------- -------------------- ------ ------ ------ -------- ------ ------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
0x823c8830 System                    4      0     58      573 ------      0                                                              
0x81f04228 smss.exe                548      4      3       21 ------      0 2010-02-26 03:34:02 UTC+0000                                 
0x822eeda0 csrss.exe               612    548     12      423      0      0 2010-02-26 03:34:04 UTC+0000                                 
0x81e5b2e8 winlogon.exe            644    548     21      521      0      0 2010-02-26 03:34:04 UTC+0000
```

and I want output like this:

```
PID   PPID

 4      0  
548      4
```

Comment: Please post a question (not just "I want..."), along with a _clear_ specification ("like this" isn't sufficient for us to know what you want). Also please do some research of your own and share what you've tried with us.

Comment: @anubhava don't waste users time by giving hints if you do know answer then post it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from this:

```
awk 'NR!=2 {print $3, $4}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
PID PPID
4 0
548 4
612 548
644 548
```

Awk will use "" as delimeter and will print 3rd and 4th group of characters (skipping line 2, because we are skipping it using `NR` variable).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk ' NR!=2 { print $3 "  " $4 }' your_file.txt
```

Comment: Why use one command when you can use three :^). `awk '!/----/ { print $3, $4 }' file` would reproduce your output.

Comment: @TomFenech for some reason it will not show `4 0` and `548 4` in the output

Comment: Better, but you can lose the `cat` and use `,` instead of `" "`.

Comment: @VadimKotov That reason would be that those lines contain `----` elsewhere. A better condition would be `NR != 2`

Comment: Yes @TomFenech, I know it. But in this case I put this to separate more the two columns.

Comment: In the end we have the same answer hahaha. Thank you all